# Left outter Join

Tags: sql, join, db2

Let's suppose i have the following query joins:

```
439.C = 365.C
444.K = 365.K
444.K = T.K
```

439,365 and 44 are tables and T is a inner select query in the main query.

I would like to create all these inner join in outter joins.
I've tried to make something this:

```
439 left outer join 365 on 439.C = 365.C
444 left outer join 365 on 444.K = 365.K left outter join T on 444.K = T.K
```

I'm using DB2 and the parser says 365 reference is ambiguos, and i'm having problems with the T alias to a inner sql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What with using the letters `K` and `C`, and the numbers, I initially thought these were _temperatures_.  **Why** would you ever name tables numerically, or use single-column variable names?  And why does this need to be in 'outer joins'?  Especially chaining them together like this, you can get some interesting results; often you really want to left-join to a table that then has an inner-join to a 'child' table.  Knowing a little more about your situation may help.  And why are you joining to `T` again - just add the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this

```
439 left outer join 365 on 439.C = 365.C
left outer join 444 on 365.K = 444.K left outer join T on 444.K = T.K
```

You have already joined the 365 with the 439 so you just need to join the 444 table with them then the t table

And change your third outer join, you wrote outter